# Problems with the calculation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers

test there in their consoles browser

1067.11-1000 = 67.1099999999999

but the correct thing 67.11

can even test the calculator windows ..

could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Google floating point math

Comment: Float point numbers are approximations, they aren't always dead on accurate...

Comment: solution:  Math.round((1067.11-1000) * 100) / 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of precision is the main disadvantage of the float type numbers - some real numbers can only be represented approximately.

You can follow **[this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)** to learn more about representation of floating point format

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are stored using base2, this creates small differences like the one you demonstrate above when converting to base10.  The difference will be even greater if use the following numbers: 1000000067.11 - 1000000000 = 67.1100000143.  This is because the level of precision decreases as the numbers calculated increases.

Comment: solution: Math.round((1067.11-1000) * 100) / 100

Comment: Sure rounding will fix the problem, I was simply expanding on the problem.  F.J.'s comment points to an excellent SO question with an excellent answer.